# Get the selected values from a list and show it in a new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I am trying to get the selected values in a list and add it to a paragraph in another page. For example in the list in the page test1.php if you select Symfony and Laravel then in page test2.php it should show you "your selected values are Symfony,Laravel"
I am still receiving the result in an alert not a new page as you can see here 
[image]

Here is my code.

test1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Tutorial</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">Select your framework</h2>
   <br />
   <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-left:200px;">
    <form method="post" id="multiple_select_form">
     <select name="framework" id="framework" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple>
      <option value="Laravel">Laravel</option>
      <option value="Symfony">Symfony</option>
      <option value="Codeigniter">Codeigniter</option>
      <option value="CakePHP">CakePHP</option>
      <option value="Zend">Zend</option>
      <option value="Yii">Yii</option>
      <option value="Slim">Slim</option>
     </select>
     <br /><br />
     <input type="hidden" name="hidden_framework" id="hidden_framework" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <br />

   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

 $('#framework').change(function(){
  $('#hidden_framework').val($('#framework').val());
 });

 $('#multiple_select_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if($('#framework').val() != '')
  {
   var form_data = $(this).serialize();
   $.ajax({
    url:"test2.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data)
    {
     //console.log(data);
     $('#hidden_framework').val('');
     $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', '');
     alert(data);
    }
   })
  }
  else
  {
   alert("Please select framework");
   return false;
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

test2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
 <body>
<p> Your selected values are 
<?php
echo  $_POST["hidden_framework"];
?>
</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion please how to adjust my code so that the message will be shown in a new page test2.php when licking on the submit button instead of this alert. Thank you very much.

Comment: We use ajax when we **dont** want the user to switch between pages. In your case you want the user to move to another page, so there is no need for ajax here. Just use regular form with `submit` button.

Comment: You need redirect, not Ajax!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code.
Will give you alert if no framework selected and on submit it will redirect to new page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Tutorial</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">Select your framework</h2>
   <br />
   <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-left:200px;">
       <form method="post" action="test2.php" id="multiple_select_form">
     <select name="framework" id="framework" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple>
      <option value="Laravel">Laravel</option>
      <option value="Symfony">Symfony</option>
      <option value="Codeigniter">Codeigniter</option>
      <option value="CakePHP">CakePHP</option>
      <option value="Zend">Zend</option>
      <option value="Yii">Yii</option>
      <option value="Slim">Slim</option>
     </select>
     <br /><br />
     <input type="hidden" name="hidden_framework" id="hidden_framework" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <br />

   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

 $('#framework').change(function(){
  $('#hidden_framework').val($('#framework').val());
 });

 $('#submit').click(function(){

  if($('#framework').val() != '')
  {
      $("#multiple_select_form").submit();
      return true;

  }
  else
  {
   alert("Please select framework");
   return false;
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `target="_blank"` to your form, it will open new window with your response  and remove `AJAX` as you want to redirect / new tab.

```
<form method="post" id="multiple_select_form" target="_blank">
```

Comment: How this data will get populated in another jsp? Please suggest

Comment: Can $_POST["hidden_framework"]; syntax will pick that value?